# How to create a URL based on Item and save if afterwards for copy in Oracle Apex 20.1

Tags: oracle, url, oracle-apex

I am working with Oracle Apex 20.1 and looking for a workaroung to create URLs based on the value of an item. The created URL should than be used to forward to other team members to visit the page with the created URL. In addition, the creator of the URL should have the option to copy the created URL and forward it to his team.

For example:

Item value: My Team 2020
Prepare URL and get URL afterwards
URL should be:
apex.somewhere.com/pls/apex/f?p=AppID:SessionID/MyTeam2020
After creation URL forward/open page with new URL
My current approach looks like this:

```
DECLARE

 l_url varchar2(2000);

l_app number := v('APP_ID');

l_session number := v('APP_SESSION');

BEGIN

l_url := APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL(

p_url => 'f?p=' || l_app || ':4:'||l_session||'::NO::P90_URL',

p_checksum_type => 'SESSION');

END;
```

What I exactly to achieve is the following. I hope this makes the situtation more clear:

- I have one page (lets say Page 10) which is used to give reviews or assessments for a defined team
- I have multiple teams with each one having a team owner
- When starting the application for the first time the team owner selects a name for his team (Page Item to be submitted) and creates a "restricted / confidential page" by creating a shared URL (also needs to be submitted in a table)
- This restricted page should be automatically redirects to the page 10 for giving the reviews
- To get access to this restricted page the team owner needs to create an unique url and provide it to his team
- Now everyone within the team should have access to the page with the created URL to give reviews
- So the view for each team changes and they can only see the results of the given reviews within in the team and not from the other teams.

Any idea how to tackle this problem or this is any best-practice solution for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you created the URL and stored it into a variable (`l_url`), in order to "save" it, store it into a table:

```
insert into urls (url) values (l_url);
```

(add additional columns, such as description, timestamp, whatever).

How to call it? Create a report page which will retrieve that value. Share its (report's) URL with colleagues so that the could access it and view URLs you saved. If you turn the saved value into a link column (in the report), even better - users will just click on it and open the page immediately.

Comment: I did try to insert the url into a table, but it doesn't save everything. For instance I couldn't save the complete url with the hostname (apexname.net). It only saved beginning from the ords/.../. I also had same problems with the session id since the client will always have an different session id then the saved one. Any idea how to solve these two problems. Thanks.